# Adding additional fields in drupal's default contact form

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to learn drupal so right now my website resides on my localhost. I am using DRUPAL 7. I have created a contact us page in my drupal site using drupal's contact module. I want to add one more fields(Phone Number) to the existing contact form and need to sent the value along with the email. How is it possible to do something like this.

I have used the following code in my contact module page

```
function mymodulename_form_contact_site_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

 $form['phone'] = array(

'#title'    => t('Phone'),
'#type'     => 'textfield',
'#required' => TRUE,
);

$order = array(

'name',
'mail',
'phone',
'subject',
'cid',
'message',
'copy',
'submit'
 );

foreach ($order as $key => $field) {

// Set/Reset the field's 
// weight to the array key value
// from our order array. 
$form[$field]['#weight'] = $key;
}
}
```

But the field is not showing up on the website page. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I made it working by creating a new module and place the similar code there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Now its all fine. I had placed the code in the existing contact module file. That was the issue. Now I create a custom module and placed the similar code there. Now its all fine.

Only change needed to make it working is instead of using this

function mymodulename_form_contact_site_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

use the below line

function mymodulename_form_contact_site_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {

Hope this helps someone.